# options[options.length] not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have jquery code that who takes values and update them in database. The problem is that it seems not working now.

it says: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Here is some portion of code:

```
$('#response_title').val('');
$("#response_new_enter").hide();
$("#response_own_enter").show();
img.attr("src","images/add_btn.png");
var options = $('#response_').attr('options');
options[options.length] = new Option(response_title, r, true, true); // error comes up in this line
alert("New Response Added Successfully.");
$("#myspan").html("New Response Added Successfully.");
$("#myspan").show();
setTimeout(function(){ $('#myspan').fadeOut(1000); }, 10000);
```

Comment: please share the relevant HTML code also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`options` is not an attribute, it is an property to try

```
var options = $('#response_').prop('options');
var options = $('#response_')[0].options; //or
```

But instead you can use jQuery to create the option like

```
$('<option />',{text: response_title, value: r, selected: true}).appendTo('#response_');
```

Comment: and so rest of the code remains as it is? correct? @Arun P Johny